# Division between columns of two different tables SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two temp tables `#Temp_tour_subvenue`:

| Grp | Days | Weeks | Months | Years |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SP1 | 2 | 6 | 1 | 2 |
| SP2 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2 |
| SP3 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2 |

And `#Temp_Sales_subvenue`:

| Grp | Days | Weeks | Months | Years |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SP1 | 6 | 12 | 2 | 4 |
| SP2 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 4 |
| SP3 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 4 |

I would like to make a new table `Closing_PC`
where each value in `#Temp_tour_subvenue` is divided by each value in `#Temp_Sales_subvenue`

| Grp | Days | Weeks | Months | Years |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Closing % SP1 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| Closing % SP2 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2 |
| Closing % SP3 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
WITH 
Closing_subvenue_sales
AS
(
SELECT * FROM #Temp_Sales_subvenue
UNION ALL
SELECT 
      'Total' AS Grp, 
      SUM(Days) As Days,
     SUM(Weeks) AS Weeks,
     SUM(Months)  AS Months,
     SUM(Years)  AS Years

FROM #Temp_Sales_subvenue
)
,
Closing_subvenue_tour
AS
(
SELECT 
        *
FROM 
        #Temp_tour_subvenue
UNION ALL
SELECT 
      'Total' AS Grp, 
      SUM(Days) As Days,
     SUM(Weeks) AS Weeks,
     SUM(Months)  AS Months,
     SUM(Years)  AS Years

FROM #Temp_tour_subvenue
)
      
SELECT 
       Closing_subvenue_sales.Grp,
       Closing_subvenue_sales.Days/Closing_subvenue_tour.Days AS Days,
       Closing_subvenue_sales.Weeks/Closing_subvenue_tour.Weeks AS Weeks,
       Closing_subvenue_sales.Months/Closing_subvenue_tour.Months AS Months,
       Closing_subvenue_sales.Years/Closing_subvenue_tour.Years AS Years


FROM Closing_subvenue_sales, Closing_subvenue_tour
```

this is what I have tried but I get a more than 3 rows in the output.

Comment: Two tables named `#Temp_tour_subvenue`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must join the two tables in order to pair corresponding records. Otherwise you get a so called [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), i.e., 3 x 3 = 9 rows, where all possible pairs are built: (SP1, SP1), (SP1, SP2), (SP1, SP3), (SP2, SP1), (SP2, SP2), (SP2, SP3), (SP3, SP1), (SP3, SP2), (SP3, SP3).

The last part of the SQL:

```sql
SELECT
   'Closing % ' + S.Grp AS Grp,
   S.Days/T.Days AS Days,
   S.Weeks/T.Weeks AS Weeks,
   S.Months/T.Months AS Months,
   S.Years/T.Years AS Years
FROM
    Closing_subvenue_sales S
    INNER JOIN Closing_subvenue_tour T
        ON S.Grp = T.Grp
```